# How to finish showing that the remainder of $5^{30009}$ divided by $7$ is $6?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I had to find the remainder when $5^{30009}$ is divided by $7.$

1. I wrote the expression like this:
   $$(A)\ x \equiv 5^{30009} \pmod 7$$
2. Found that: $$ 5^6 \equiv 1 \pmod 7 $$
3. Then wrote $(A)$ like this: $$ (5^6)^{50001}\cdot 5^3 \equiv 5^{30009} \pmod 7$$
4. Replacing $5^6$ with $1$, the expression becomes,
   $$5^3 \equiv 5^{30009} \pmod 7 $$

Now I'm not sure how to continue from there. I can easily verify that $$125 = 17\cdot7 + 6$$ So, the remainder is $6.$ But is showing that enough or I should keep using congruence notation to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you've done all the work (in a good way, well done!). The last step would be to note that the identity $125=17\cdot7+6$ implies $5^3\equiv6\pmod7$. There's nothing new that you need to add, other than to show that your calculations actually demonstrate what you've been asked to demonstrate.

Comment: \pmod{7} will produce the correct spacing, typeface, and the parentheses around "mod 7".

Comment: Did you mean $5001$ where you typed $50001$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2033639/mod-of-numbers-with-large-exponents-modular-order-reduction)

Comment: $\!\bmod 7\!:\ \color{#c00}{5^3\equiv -1}\Rightarrow 5^{30009}\equiv (\color{#c00}{5^3})^{10003}\equiv (\color{#c00}{-1})^{10003}\equiv -1\,$ by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). $ $ **Or** use $\,5^{\color{#c00}6}\equiv 1\pmod{\!7},\ \color{#0a0}{30009\equiv 3\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{6}}}\Rightarrow 5^{\color{#0a0}{30009}}\equiv 5^{\color{#0a0}3}\pmod{\!7}\,$ by [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) in the  linked dupe (whose proof also uses the Congruence Power Rule as above, using $\,\color{#c00}{5^6\equiv 1}),\,$ as you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, your proof is fine.

Here is one that involves even less calculations, exploiting negative values of congruences:

$5^{30009}\equiv(-2)^{30009}\equiv (-8)^{10003}\equiv(-1)^{10003}\equiv -1\equiv 6\pmod{7}$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).